# Como obtener registros donde los valores en una columna sean mayor a 1?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
//Cuando presione el boton semanal que me muestre registos siempre y cuando
//la columna semanas tenga un valor entre el 1 y el 12
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("string"))
    {
        conexion.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Tb1 where Semanas between @Date1 and @Date2", conexion);


        sda1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date1", DateTimePicker1.Value));
        sda1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Date2", DateTimePicker2.Value));

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda1.Fill(dt);
        this.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: no entendi, que es eso de `columna[8]`? no era que la columna es `Semanas`

Comment: Si la columna es del tipo fecha que tiene que ver un filtro por rango entre dos fechas, deberias pasarle que semana quiere recuperar o sea un solo parametro numerico

Comment: Columna [8] quise dar a entender que es en donde originalmente va y cae ese valor capturado en el formulario hacia la  base de datos sqlserver, se llama semanas pero corresponde al numero de columna 8.

Comment: ahh ok pero esa columna es numerica, entonces no entiendo porqu quieres filtrarla usando fechas?

Comment: Eres el mismo que me dio respuesta alla en el foro de MSDN jajaj estas en todos lados!! Bien por ti y gracias por ayudar. Bueno, lo que busco hacer basicamente Leandro es que, por ejemplo, el usuario pueda filtrar entre "x" rango de fechas a que clientes el les realizo un prestamo a 12 semanas, y asi cuando quiera consultar la informacion la pueda consultar por separado, de los clientes que son a 12 semanas y el resto de sus clientes que no les maneja ningun tipo de plazo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si entendi bien tu pregunta, pero puedes usar un lambda para sacar los datos de la celda (algo como esto)

```
Var x= DataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRows>().Where(f=>f.Cells["NombreDetuColumna"].Value>="1").ToList()
```

para luego cargarlos 
//esa lista la cargas al Datagridview con el DataSource

Comment: Pero menciona que quiere filtrar en la db, no en el grid

Comment: En la db las columnas no funcionan por indice "[8]"

Comment: Entonces le propones traerse todos los registros de la tabla, lo cuales puedes ser miles, para filtrar en el control?

Answer (score 0):

En `T-SQL` cuentas cn la funcion

[DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

algo como esto

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

    using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("string connection"))
    {

        string query = "select * from Tb1 where DATEPART(wk, Semanas) = @semana";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conexion);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semana", Convert.ToInt32(txtSemana.Text));

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
    this.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Usas la funcion `DATEPART(wk, Semanas)` para obtener la `semana del año` y solo filtras por el numero de la semana que quieres obtener